# What is the standard way to publish a Deno application for other people to use?

Tags: node.js, npm, deno

When I create an application on Node.js, I perform the following steps to publish it for other people:

1. Add a `main.js` file, which calls node:

```js
#!/usr/bin/env -S node --stack-size=10000

console.log("Hello world!")
```

2. Include it on `package.json`:

```
  ...
  "name": "my_app",
  ...
  "bin": {
    "my_app": "src/main.js"
  },
  ...
```

3. Type `npm publish`.

And done: anyone can then now install it by typing `npm i -g my_app`, and it will be made available to use on the terminal by typing `my_app`. What are the equivalent steps to publish an application built using Deno instead?

Answer (score 3):

#### How to publish a Deno command-line application

1. Create an entry file (ex: `main.ts`).
2. Host your project somewhere.
3. Install it anywhere using the URL to `main.ts`:

```
deno install -n your_app https://your_url/your_app/main.ts
```

#### Passing options

You can pass Deno options in the same way you would for `deno run`:

```
deno --unstable install -n your_app --allow-all URL_HERE
```

#### Using Github

If you have a Github repository, you can get a URL to your file by browsing to it, and clicking on "Raw". It will be something like:

```
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/your_org/your_app/tree/master/main.ts
```

This URL can be used to install your app.

#### Using deno.land/x

You can also register a Github repository on `https://deno.land/x`. This will give you a shorter url:

```
https://deno.land/x/your_app/main.ts
```

As well as a way to keep track of immutable versions:

```
https://deno.land/x/your_app@version/main.ts
```

Thanks for the devs on [Deno's Discord](https://discord.com/invite/deno) for the help.

Comment: It would be useful to add that the `version` in the deno.land/x URL corresponds to a git tag

Answer (score 1):

Since deno uses urls for dependencies you do not need to publish anything from your cli. You can simply host it as a public repo on github. Then you can add it to their third-party library [here](https://deno.land/x) by clicking on the 'publish a module' button